# Why changing the style of the column header is throwing error?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which is loading the columns from databse stored procedure directly.

I am changing its style to **bold** for few headers of columns and not all.

```
 dgvFunctionalLocation.Columns("FL").HeaderCell.Style.Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
```

but is not working and throw error.

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.ShouldSerializeHeaderText()
```

Comment: That's a method, not an error. Are you saying, without actually saying, that it is throwing an exception when that method is called? If so, when exactly is that method called? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: I am only using this line dgvFunctionalLocation.Columns("FL").HeaderCell.Style.Font = New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold)

Comment: and it throws exception that HeaderText should be serialized.

Comment: No it doesn't because there is no such exception. That is a method that returns a Boolean value indicating whether the header text should be serialised or not.

Comment: Are you sure you are using winforms datagridview and not some third party control (Telerik, Syncfusion, DevExpress etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new project with a `DataGridView` and successfully executed this code:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim table As New DataTable

        With table.Columns
            .Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
            .Add("Name", GetType(String))
        End With

        With table.Rows
            .Add(1, "Peter")
            .Add(2, "Paul")
            .Add(3, "Mary")
        End With

        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font, DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I can't see why the same sort of thing wouldn't work for you. If it doesn't, you need to do what you should have in the first place and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that explicitly demonstrates the issue.